# Persistent Popover with VoiceOver

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, voiceover

I have an iPad popover with a button that triggers a modal segue to a full-screen view controller.  It works fine and the popover dismisses itself.  But, when VoiceOver is on, the labels of the popover persist and this interferes with the user hearing the new screen's VoiceOver labels.  Even though the popover is dismissed, I can see the outlines of its labels as they are selected in VoiceOver.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, placing:

```
self.view.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;
```

in my destination view controller's viewWillAppear: resolved the issue.